# How do i import imdb list files into mysql database on windows?

Tags: mysql, database, imdbpy

Am using MYSQL, imdbpy(to import data). I have never used imdbpy before and have no idea of how python script works.Here is the list of text files from which am gonna use a few to import into my database. 
ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/

Here is the link of imdbpy link that am trying to follow.
http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/docs/README.sqldb.txt

I quite don't understand this part :

*Create a database named "imdb" (or whatever you like),
using the tool provided by your database; as an example, for MySQL
you will use the 'mysqladmin' command:
  # mysqladmin -p create imdb
For PostgreSQL, you have to use the "createdb" command:
  # createdb -W imdb

To create the tables and to populate the database, you must run
the imdbpy2sql.py script:
  # imdbpy2sql.py -d /dir/with/plainTextDataFiles/ -u 'URI'

Where the 'URI' argument is a string representing the connection
to your database, with the schema:
  scheme://[user[:password]@]host[:port]/database[?parameters]*

How do i run that imdbpy2sql.py script?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Python installed, you would run "imdbpy2sql.py -d /dir/with/plainTextDataFiles/ -u 'URI'" from the command prompt.

Note: The command prompt will need to be 'sitting' in the directory where imdbpy2sql.py exists or you will need to predicate imdbpy2sql.py with the full directory path.

Answer (score 0):

The script imdbpy2sql.py can be found on their site: https://bitbucket.org/alberanid/imdbpy/src/ed8b3d354c9f1e2de7056d78b21e49f64ee52591/bin/imdbpy2sql.py?at=default

Since the script doesn't seem dependent on any other files, it should be sufficient to copy and paste the code to your current repository.